# derivation of limitation of karl pearsons coefficient of skewness

Tags: skewness

can someone help me with the derivation of limitation of karl pearson's coefficient of skewness i.e

```
-3 <= Sk <= 3; where Sk is the karl pearson's coefficient of skewness.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which coefficient is that? He invented several.

Comment: coefficient of skewness in terms of mean and median: 3(M-Md)/S.D

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3787/empirical-relationship-between-mean-median-and-mode/3790#3790.

Comment: (mean $-$ median) / SD is bounded by $-1$ and $1$. It's only mentioned briefly by Pearson. He placed more emphasis on measuring skewness with respect to the mean and mode, whereas now we use much more a moment-based measure, which yet again can be found in his work (and is a re-invention of others' work).

Comment: A simple proof of those bounds is in the post whuber links to. Also see here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians ... several other proofs may be found in the literature, such as O’Cinneide, C.A. (1990),    
"The Mean Is Within One Standard Deviation of Any Median,"  
*The American Statistician*, November,  Vol. 4, No. 4, 292-293
 ...see also Hotelling, H. and Solomons, L. M.  (1932), “The Limits of a Measure of Skewness,” The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 3, 141-142.